# Cannot change PostgresSQL default user password

Tags: password, postgresql, pgadmin

Recently I have faced with issue that I cannot change password that is used in pgAdmin for connection to remote database ...

In `pg_hba.conf` (PostgresSQL 12) I have the following login capabilities:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
hostnossl       all     all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

I tried to change password for `postgres` user, also tried to change password of `postgres` role in database nothing helped ...

Is there a way to change default password for connection to PostgresSQL ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show how you tried to change the password? There are two ways to do it. Did you see any errors? 

Comment: @matigo I tried to do it in Linux using passwd

Comment: @matigo Thanks for solution but I tried to do solution that you provided below before but it does not help !! I still can connect to database using password postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I used the following line in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
...
hostnossl       all     all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

That is way it was not necessary to use password for connection with database

I changed it to:

```
hostnossl       all     all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Answer (score 1):

The `passwd` command is used to change the password of a Linux user account. To change the password of a PostgreSQL account, you will need to do it from within PostgreSQL. There are generally two ways to do this:

#### Via the Command Line

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Switch to the `postgres` account (or one that has admin rights for the database engine):

   ```
   sudo -i -u postgres
   ```
3. Connect to the database engine:

   ```
   psql
   ```
4. Set the password:

   ```
   \password postgres
   ```
5. When prompted, enter the new password
6. Exit (`q`uit):

   ```
   \q
   ```

#### Via a SQL Command

1. Connect to PostgreSQL with an admin-level account
2. Set the password:

   ```
   ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'superSecretPassword!123';
   ```

From here, you can edit your pgAdmin configuration for the new password.

**Note:** *It is generally poor practice to connect to a PostgreSQL database remotely using the* `postgres` *account as this is an easier target for people with bad intentions to hit. If you are administering a database remotely, consider creating a user account with admin privileges. If the remote server is running Linux, you can further protect the database by connecting via an SSH tunnel.*

Comment: All this steps do not help ... I changed password using 1 and 2 solutions and still can connects to postgres database using default password postgres

Comment: For example when I enter the password postgres in Please enter the password for the user 'postgres' to connect the server - "Stuffs PostgresSQL 12"